# Create a table in excel using data from Python2.7

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to export my data to an excel file.  My problem is that my data comes from a itertools.combination and I cannot figure out how to export all of the combinations and their data into an excel file

My subset comes from an input file that looks like

```
carbon_1    xcoordinate    ycoordinate   zcoordinate
```

For n number of carbons

For reference, my code is

```
subset = cmd[['carbon','x_coord', 'y_coord','z_coord']]
coordinate_values = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]

atoms = coordinate_values
atomPairs = itertools.combinations(atoms, 2)

atoms_dict = {k:"carbon_{}".format(i) for i,k in enumerate(atoms,1)}
    print("Computing distance between {} and {}".format(atoms_dict[pair[0]],atoms_dict[pair[1]]))
```

I then have a simple definition to calculate distance, d, and the end of my code is

```
if d >= 1.4 and d < 1.6:
    bond = 1
elif d >= 1.2 and d < 1.4:
    bond = 2
elif d >= 1 and d < 1.2:
    bond = 3
else:
    bond = 0
```

The output of my code for each combination is

```
Computing distance between carbon_1 and carbon_2
2
```

I would like to be able to export the 'bond' for each combination into an excel sheet.  The excel sheet would be able to grow if I add another coordinate to the combination, aka another 'carbon'.  The excel sheet would look something like this:

```
"Carbon pair"                 "Bond"
Carbon 1 to Carbon 2             2
Carbon 2 to Carbon 3             3
```

I am very new to Python and I am unsure how to export anything into excel, let alone create a table in excel that will satisfy these conditions.  Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `openpyxl` is a very good python module: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it seems, that you currently not need any excel features so I guess you can use a csv-file as export. This is much easier to use. See [Python 2.7 CSV doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) for more information. csv-files can easily be imported in excel.

If you really need to create an excel file, then you should take a look at [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io). I've used it some time ago and it is really easy to use.

To be able to grow your table, you should think about using a matrix to store your date. So instead of using something like this:

```
"Carbon pair"                 "Bond"
Carbon 1 to Carbon 2             2
Carbon 2 to Carbon 3             3
```

a better way to grow your carbon database is this attempt:

```
Bond     Carbon1     Carbon2     Carbon3
Carbon1     -           5           1
Carbon2     3           -           4
Carbon3     5           1           -
```

If you use this matrix notation, then you will be able to access your data faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to help you directly, but I suggest checking out the [XLWT module](http://www.python-excel.org/). Documentation can be hard to find, but some Google searches for "XLWT" and "Python Excel" should lead you to some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** This question is open-ended so answers are likely to be experience based. There is no one solution better than others.

I use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) for excel work as I can save files in latest `xlsx` format.

You can install it using

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Since I dont have all the code, I am assuming you will be able to get the needed data in a list of list , or some format that is comma seperated and that can be manipulated.

For example, I have data in a list of list as below.
Header information in:

```
headers = ["Carbon pair","Bond"]
```

and carbon data in

```
carbon_data = [["Carbon 1 to Carbon 2",2],["Carbon 2 to Carbon 3",3]]
```

Once you have that, you can create a new workbook and work with data just as you would in excel.
 Demo Code:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

headers = ["Carbon pair","Bond"]   

carbon_data= [["Carbon 1 to Carbon 2",2],["Carbon 2 to Carbon 3",3]]
dest_filename = 'carbon_data.xlsx'

#Open new workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "carbon_pairs_bonds"

#Add headers
ws1.append(headers)

#Add data
for row in carbon_data:
    ws1.append(row)

#Save workbook
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Once you have created a file , you can add , manipulate columns, rows just as you would in excel. The `openpyxl` site has detailed tutorial and examples. There is a `openpyxl` tag within SO that you can refer to for questions.

Hope this helps.
**carbon_data.xlsx**

[image]